# SSRS Grouping Totals Inquiry

Tags: reporting-services

Good day experts!
Would like to ask on how can do below with SSRS?
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxFc.png)

I was able to create the table but struggling to figure out on how to declare TotalWon/TotalLost value.
Expression for Total is =Sum(Fields!Calculated_TotalQuote.Value)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I have set up the table but unable to figure out on how to divide totals on each group.
[image]

Comment: You'll need to share your report design, including any row grouping details, show the current expressions in your totals at the moment, and a sample of data from your dataset query would also be helpful. This should be simple to do but without this info giving an answer will be a bit of guesswork.